# Improve seq scan filter cost on column being NOT NULL

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I have this following query with explain:

```
SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE ("carts"."content_updated_at" IS NOT NULL)  ORDER BY carts.content_updated_at desc LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
                                  QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=208231.51..208231.63 rows=50 width=1267)
   ->  Sort  (cost=208231.51..208558.04 rows=130615 width=1267)
         Sort Key: content_updated_at DESC
         ->  Seq Scan on carts  (cost=0.00..203892.57 rows=130615 width=1267)
               Filter: (content_updated_at IS NOT NULL)
```

If I add an index on `content_updated_at IS NOT NULL`, will it improve the performance of this query?

Here is the explain without the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE ("carts"."content_updated_at" IS NOT NULL) LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
                               QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..75.03 rows=50 width=1270)
   ->  Seq Scan on carts  (cost=0.00..204483.29 rows=136264 width=1270)
         Filter: (content_updated_at IS NOT NULL)
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE ("carts"."content_updated_at" IS NOT NULL)  ORDER BY carts.content_updated_at desc LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0;
                                                           QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=209373.22..209373.34 rows=50 width=1270) (actual time=18482.469..18482.620 rows=50 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=209373.22..209717.30 rows=137633 width=1270) (actual time=18482.463..18482.517 rows=50 loops=1)
         Sort Key: content_updated_at DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 50kB
         ->  Seq Scan on carts  (cost=0.00..204801.15 rows=137633 width=1270) (actual time=0.553..18283.431 rows=139318 loops=1)
               Filter: (content_updated_at IS NOT NULL)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 3023640
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seq scan is due to the ORDER BY, not the IS NOT NULL.  You should put an index on content_updated_at.  It could be a partial index if you always add the IS NOT NULL to the where clause:

```
CREATE INDEX ON carts (content_updated_at) WHERE content_updated_at IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Oh, I thought, reading this `Seq Scan on carts  (cost=0.00..203892.57 rows=130615 width=1267)`, that its coz of the `IS NOT NULL`. How did you make the conclusion?

Comment: I've updated the explain output without the `ORDER BY`

Comment: Without using EXPLAIN ANALYZE, it's easy to miss a few details.  `SELECT * ... LIMIT 50` will just select the first 50 rows it finds (with a sequential scan) and stop.  `SELECT * ... ORDER BY x LIMIT 50` will need to sort everything and then return the first 50 rows.  It's significantly more expensive.

Comment: Thanks for that insight. I'm updating the question with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.